# React cannot setState in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
const [soilInfo, setSoilInfo] = useState([]);
  const [ambient, setAmbient] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSoil = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8081/soil_info").then((response) => {
        setSoilInfo(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
    }
    getSoil();
    console.log(soilInfo);
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAmbient = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8081/ambient").then((response) => {
        setAmbient(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
    }
    getAmbient();
    console.log(ambient);
  }, [])
```

I tried debugging by printing in get function and after get function. It turns out that soilInfo and ambient are null sets. The response was fine. [This is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HsE2.png)

Comment: `I tried debugging by printing in get function and after get function.` like, you called `setSoilInfo(response.data)` and then on the next line did `console.log(soilInfo)`?

Comment: *"I tried debugging by printing"* - The code shown doesn't appear to "print" anything.  What specific operation in the code shown isn't working as expected?  Please elaborate on the problem you are observing (and how you are observing it).

Comment: I tried console.log(response) inside the getSoil function and console.log(soilInfo) after getSoil function called in useEffect then I delete those lines after I know what's the problem. the response is a set of object in json format which is fine, soilInfo was an empty set, so I assume that setState function was not working.

Comment: @plwie: The code shown has no `console.log` statements.  If you're asking why some other code doesn't work as expected, please show *that* code and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected.  Based on your description, it sounds like you're trying to log the result of an asynchronous operation before that operation completes.  But that's only a guess, because you're asking about code you aren't showing us and you're assuming that your actual code must be correct and that React must be broken, which is a fundamentally flawed assumption.

Comment: I added the code which has console.log in the answer section below, and also the result.

Comment: @plwie: Is the answer below actually an answer?  Did you resolve the problem?  If the answer below is meant to be part of the question, add that information to the question.  Also, don't just show the output, specify what you think is *wrong* with the output.  So far I'm not seeing any actual problem here.  You're fetching data from the server and setting that data to state values.  What isn't working about that?  Be specific about the problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: soilInfo is still a null set, also ambient. the fetching is working properly, from the result I get from console.log(response.data) in both get functions. the problem is the results from console.log(soilInfo) and console.log(ambient) are null sets. that makes me think there is a problem with setState in the get function.

Comment: The first time I fetching, it was fine, but every time I refreshed the page, the error occurs.

Comment: @plwie: `getSoil` and `getAmbient` are asynchronous functions.  You're trying to log their result before they've completed fetching that result.  The code is working fine, you just have an incorrect expectation.  Examine the state updates in the resulting component renders instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have a couple of ideas here:

1. Your axios `get` call could be failing. This would result in your `then` clause not being called. I would try logging out the response or adding a `catch` clause to verify the request is working.
2. Both `setSoilInfo` and `setAmbient` are expecting a list at the moment (if you are using Typescript at least). What data type is `response.data`? If you know, I'd recommend typing your useState like so: `useState<TYPE[]>`. Then you can get some type help.

Let me know if you have questions about either of the above.

Comment: I tried console.log(response) inside the getSoil function and console.log(soilInfo) after getSoil function called in useEffect. the response is a set of object in json format which is fine, soilInfo was an empty set, so I assume that setState function was not working. At first run this function worked perfectly but after I refreshed the page, the error occurs.